# ember-simple-auth deferReadiness until user is loaded

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I am using ember-cli-simple-auth and have extended the session object to include the currentUser which is retrieved from the `/me` endpoint. However, when the page is reloaded and the user is logged in there is a delay until the logged in user information is loaded. I would like to defer the apps readiness until the user is retrieved.

I have this in a `custom-session` initializer.

```
import Session from 'simple-auth/session';
export default {
  name: 'custom-session',
  initialize: function(container, app) {
    var _app = app;
    var SessionWithCurrentUser = Session.extend({
        currentUser: function() {
            var _this = this;
            return this.container.lookup('store:main').find('me', '').then(function(data){
                _app.advanceReadiness();
                _this.set('currentUser', data);
            }, function(data){
                console.log('failed');
                return data;
            });
        }.property()
    });

    container.register('session:withCurrentUser', SessionWithCurrentUser);
    app.deferReadiness();
  }
};
```

It appears that `advanceReadiness` is never called so the app never loads. I am very new to ember and am still getting my head around the container so am unsure of how this works. What am I doing wrong?

### Update

```
export default {
  name: 'custom-session',
  initialize: function(container, app) {
    var _app = app;
    var SessionWithCurrentUser = Session.extend({
        currentUser: function() {
            var _this = this;
            return _this.container.lookup('store:main').find('me', '').then(function(data){
                _app.advanceReadiness();
                _this.set('currentUser', data);
            }, function(data){
                console.log('failed');
                return data;
            });
        }.property()
    });

    var session = SessionWithCurrentUser.create();
    container.register('session:withCurrentUser', session, { instantiate: false });
    app.deferReadiness();
    session.currentUser();
  }
};
```

From the answer suggested I changed it to this but this gives the error `undefined is not a function` coming from the call to `session.currentUser()`.

### Stack trace

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function app/initializers/custom-session.js:28
__exports__.default.initialize app/initializers/custom-session.js:28
(anonymous function) vendor.js:14807
visit vendor.js:15216
visit vendor.js:15214
visit vendor.js:15214
visit vendor.js:15214
DAG.topsort vendor.js:15312
Namespace.extend.runInitializers vendor.js:14804
Namespace.extend._initialize vendor.js:14689
Backburner.run vendor.js:12247
apply vendor.js:30430
run vendor.js:29048
runInitialize vendor.js:14488
fire vendor.js:3184
self.fireWith vendor.js:3296
jQuery.extend.ready vendor.js:3502
completed
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never calling the `currentUser` method in the initializer. You'd need to change that to

```
var session = SessionWithCurrentUser.create()
container.register('session:withCurrentUser', session, { instantiate: false });
app.deferReadiness();
session.currentUser();
```

Of course you'd have to call `app.advanceReadiness();` in the case where the user could not be loaded as well, otherwise the app would never start up in that case.

Comment: Please see my update. This has not worked as expected

Comment: Please add a stack trace for the exception

Comment: Like I said in the update the line that calls `session.currentUser()`

Comment: OK, you'd need to debug through that - there's nothing that strikes me immediately. Also you shouldn't use `_this.container` but just `container`. There's also no need to define the additional variable `_app`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have absolutely no idea where to start debugging this

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the initializer to find the exact line that causes the error.